# How can I run Unit Test from a dependency library

Tags: java, unit-testing, gradle, build.gradle

I Have a requirement for our java projects.
We have some common unit tests for our multiple projects.

So Instead of copy-pasting them to all projects.
I want to have them in a library and include that as a dependency in our all projects to run tests.

I am using Gradle as build tool.

Example -

```
dependencies {
    implementation "com.abc.dependencies"
    //This commonProject-testkit  have all then common unit tests
    testImplementation "**com.abcComapny:commonProject-testkit:0.0.1**"
}

configurations {
    testImplementation
}

task driverTest(type: Test) {
   // THIS LINE THROWS ERROR 
   //"Resolving configuration 'testImplementation' directly is not allowed"

   testClassesDirs = zipTree(configurations.testImplementation.asPath)    
}
check.dependsOn driverTest
```

Comment: Your question is a bit vague and raises few questions. Maybe you could give a minimal example of your "common unit test" and two units to be tested (with beforementioned commo unit test) in two different projects?

Comment: I have made some progress and have update example Hope it makes sense now.

Comment: Good addition but I was hoping to see for some java code snippets, how (test) and what you are testing (two examples that same test apply).

Comment: They are java unit test, no Issues with them, 
Can't post the company's code on stackoverflow.

The main Issue it How to include them with my project

Comment: No company code. Just an example of your own. The issue is that making same unit test to two or more "units" does not make sense to me.

Comment: It also doesn't make sense to me. But if there is actually a point to it, you can solve it by using `testRuntimeClasspath` instead of `testImplementation`. The latter is a configuration that contributes to the final classpath, but you can't resolve it to individual artifacts. For that, use the former.

Comment: I Hope this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12175848/run-junit-tests-from-a-dependency-jar-in-eclipse

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE ANSWER**

I was able to solve this issue, Posting it If someone encounters a similar problem

```
dependencies {
    implementation "com.abc.dependencies"
    //This commonProject-testkit  have all then common unit tests
    testKit "com.abcComapny:commonProject-testkit:0.0.1"
    compile configurations.testKit
}

configurations {
    testKit 
}
task copyTestKitToLib(type: Copy, dependsOn: copyTestKitToLib) {
  from configurations.testKit
  into "$buildDir/output/lib"
}
task driverTest(type: Test) {
   testClassesDirs = zipTree("$buildDir/output/lib/commonProject-testkit:0.0.1.jar")    
}
check.dependsOn copyTestKitToLib
check.dependsOn driverTest
```

Answer (score 0):

How about packaging these tests into a module, then include it to your projects?